# Django NoReverseMatch Solution?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am carrying out a project for an online grocery store. I want to have a 'View Ratings' button beneath each item within the store that takes users to a ratings.html page where they can view previous ratings and also submit their own using a form. However, I am running into the following error when I attempt to click the 'View Ratings' button beneath an item. Also, if I managed to get this fixed, is there a way I can make it so I can view the ratings in my admin area? Any help is appreciated!

```
Reverse for 'ratings' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ratings/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ratings/1/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'ratings' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ratings/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
Exception Location: C:\Users\Sammc\OneDrive - Ulster University\Desktop\django_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during:  customer.views.Ratings
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Sammc\OneDrive - Ulster University\Desktop\django_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.7
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Sammc\\OneDrive - Ulster '
 'University\\Desktop\\django_project\\groc',
 'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\Sammc\\OneDrive - Ulster '
 'University\\Desktop\\django_project\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Sammc\\OneDrive - Ulster '
 'University\\Desktop\\django_project\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 04 May 2023 14:54:43 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Sammc\OneDrive - Ulster University\Desktop\django_project\groc\customer\templates\customer\ratings.html, error at line 15

Reverse for 'ratings' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ratings/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
5   <div class="container">
6       <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
7           <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center">
8               <h1>Item Ratings</h1>
9               <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
10          </div>
11      </div>
12  
13      <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
14          <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-center">
15              <form method="GET" action="{% url 'ratings' item_id %}">
16                  <div class="form-group">
17                      <label for="name">Name:</label>
18                      <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" required>
19                  </div>
20                  <div class="form-group">
21                      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
22                      <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="4" required></textarea>
23                  </div>
24                  <div class="form-group">
25                      <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
```

I am not sure where the issue is occuring so ill supply the code for all relveant files (groceries.html, ratings.html, models.py, urls.py, views.py, forms.py):

groceries.html:

```
{% block content %}

<p>
    <button style="font-size: 16px;" onclick="increaseTextSize()">+A</button>
    <button style="font-size: 16px;" onclick="decreaseTextSize()">-A</button>
</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h1>Groceries</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'groceries-search' %}">
                <div class="md-form mt-0 active-cyan-2">
                    <input class="form-control" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
        {% for item in groc_items %}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 text-center mb-5">
            <img class="rounded" src="{{ item.image.url }}" width=350 height="300">
            <h5 class="mt-3">{{ item.name }}</h5>
            <p>Price: £{{ item.price }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
            <a href="{% url 'ratings' item.id %}">View Ratings</a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

ratings.html:

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h1>Item Ratings</h1>
            <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'ratings' item_id %}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" rows="4" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="rating" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select rating</option>
                        <option value="5">5 - Excellent</option>
                        <option value="4">4 - Very Good</option>
                        <option value="3">3 - Good</option>
                        <option value="2">2 - Fair</option>
                        <option value="1">1 - Poor</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
        {% if ratings %}
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h3>Reviews</h3>
            <hr>
            {% for rating in ratings %}
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ rating.name }} - {{ rating.get_rating_display }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ rating.comment }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


class ShopItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_images/')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='item')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class OrderModel(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(
        'ShopItem', related_name='order', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    out_for_delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Order: {self.created_on.strftime("%b %d %I: %M %p")}'
    
class Rating(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey('ShopItem', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ratings')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}'s rating for {self.item.name}"
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from customer.views import Index, About, Order, OrderConfirmation, OrderPayConfirmation, Groceries, GroceriesSearch, Ratings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('about/', About.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('ratings/<int:item_id>/', Ratings.as_view(), name='ratings'),
    path('groceries/', Groceries.as_view(), name='groceries'),
    path('groceries/search', GroceriesSearch.as_view(), name='groceries-search'),
    path('order/', Order.as_view(), name='order'),
    path('order-confirmation/<int:pk>', OrderConfirmation.as_view(), name='order-confirmation'),
    path('payment-confirmation/', OrderPayConfirmation.as_view(), name='order-pay-confirmation'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
from urllib import request
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views import View
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import ShopItem, OrderModel, Rating
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
from customer.forms import RatingForm

class Index(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'customer/index.html')


class About(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'customer/about.html')


class Order(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # get every item from each category
        foods = ShopItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Food')
        meats = ShopItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Meat')
        fruits = ShopItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Fruit')
        cleaning = ShopItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Cleaning')
        bakery = ShopItem.objects.filter(category__name__contains='Bakery')

        # pass into context
        context = {
            'foods': foods,
            'meats': meats,
            'fruits': fruits,
            'cleaning': cleaning,
            'bakery': bakery,
        }

        # render the template
        return render(request, 'customer/order.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        county = request.POST.get('county')
        postcode = request.POST.get('postcode')

        order_items = {
            'items': []
        }

        items = request.POST.getlist('items[]')

        for item in items:
            print(item)
            shop_item = ShopItem.objects.get(pk=int(item))
            item_data = {
                'id': shop_item.pk,
                'name': shop_item.name,
                'price': shop_item.price
            }

            order_items['items'].append(item_data)

            price = 0
            item_ids = []

        for item in order_items['items']:
            price += item['price']
            item_ids.append(item['id'])

        order = OrderModel.objects.create(
            price=price,
            name=name,
            email=email,
            address=address,
            city=city,
            county=county,
            postcode=postcode
        )
        order.items.add(*item_ids)

        # After everything is done, send confirmation email to user
        body = ('Thanks for your order! Your order is being prepared and will be delivered as soon as possible!\n'
            f'Total price: {price}\n'
            'Thanks for your order!')
        
        send_mail(
            'Thanks For Your Order!',
            body,
            'example@example.com',
            [email],
            fail_silently=False
        )

        context = {
            'items': order_items['items'],
            'price': price
        }

        return redirect('order-confirmation', pk=order.pk)

class OrderConfirmation(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        order = OrderModel.objects.get(pk=pk)

        context = {
            'pk': order.pk,
            'items': order.items,
            'price': order.price,
        }

        return render(request, 'customer/order_confirmation.html', context)

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        data = json.loads(request.body)

        if data['isPaid']:
            order = OrderModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            order.is_paid = True
            order.save()

        return redirect('payment-confirmation')


class OrderPayConfirmation(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'customer/order_pay_confirmation.html')
    

def change_text_size(request, size):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.set_cookie('text_size', size)
    return response

class Groceries(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        groc_items = ShopItem.objects.all()

        context = {
            'groc_items': groc_items
        }

        return render(request, 'customer/groceries.html', context)
    
class GroceriesSearch(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")

        groc_items = ShopItem.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query) |
            Q(price__icontains=query) |
            Q(description__icontains=query)
        )

        context = {
            'groc_items': groc_items
        }

        return render(request, 'customer/groceries.html', context)
    

class Ratings(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'customer/ratings.html')
    
        
def ratings(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(ShopItem, pk=item_id)
    ratings = item.ratings.all().order_by('-created_at')
    form = RatingForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RatingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            rating = form.save(commit=False)
            rating.item = item
            rating.save()
            return redirect('ratings', item_id=item.id)
    
    context = {
        'item': item,
        'ratings': ratings,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'ratings.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from .models import Rating

class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['name', 'comment', 'rating']
```

I was expecting to be taken to a page with a form to leave a rating.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
return redirect('ratings', item_id=item.id)
```

to this using [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(
    reverse('ratings', args=[item.id])
)
```

Comment: Still getting same error :(

Comment: Also, change `{% url 'ratings' item_id %}` to `{% url 'ratings' item.id %}`.

Comment: @marco redirect [makes reversion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) out of the box

Comment: @marco, made that change, still getting error. Thought I maybe had to change item_id to item.id in url aswell, but that returns error in cmd.

Comment: @Sam you can keep the variable name in the urls file. Make sure `ratings.html` is always rendered with an item.

Comment: changed it to item.id in ratings.html, still no luck